# Flutter pass state data to function

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to modify the state outside the `showDialog` function. Here is my existing code:

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
              content: Text(contentText),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Change"),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

I would like to  modify the state of text in the dialog from outside.

So instead of :

```
setState(() {
                      contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                    });
```

in the StatefulBuilder,

I want to refactor and write a function that I call e.g

```
updateContent(){
   setState(() {
                          contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                        });
}
```

However I am unable to update the text this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in contextText variable declaration place. Make it as class variable

```
String contentText = "Content of Dialog";

_whereShowDialogTriggered()
{
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        //String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
        return StatefulBuilder(
...
```

Comment: it has to belong to showDialog() in order for setState to work and the widget to update

Answer (score 0):

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            updateContent() {
              setState(() {
                contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
              });
            }

            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
              content: Text(contentText),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: updateContent,
                  child: Text("Change"),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Although, at this point it is probably better to just make a new (StatefulWidget) for the dialog.

Comment: Can I extract updateContent() out further?

Comment: `updateContent` must be defined in the same scope (or lower) as the variable it used and it needs the `setState` function provided by the builder. So moving it higher than in my code will make things worse (you'd have to inject setState). If you want better encapsulation, define a new widget for everything that is now created by showDialog's builder.